# req.body is empty on posts

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, post, postman

I've been searching the site for a while with no luck. I have:

```
module.exports.locationsCreate = function (req, res) {
  console.log(req.body);
  Loc.create({
    name: req.body.name,
    address: req.body.address,
    facilities: req.body.facilities.split(","),
    coords: [parseFloat(req.body.lng), parseFloat(req.body.lat)],
    openingTimes: [{
      days: req.body.days1,
      opening: req.body.opening1,
      closing: req.body.closing1,
      closed: req.body.closed1,
    }, {
      days: req.body.days2,
      opening: req.body.opening2,
      closing: req.body.closing2,
      closed: req.body.closed2,
    }]
  }, function(err, location) {
    if(err) {
      sendJsonResponse(res, 400, err);
    } else {
      sendJsonResponse(res, 201, location)
    }
  });
};
```

and I'm getting TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined and my req.body is empty when making posts even when I have "X-www-form-urlencoded" selected in Postman. In my app.js file I have:

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
require('./app_api/models/db');

var index = require('./app_server/routes/index');
var indexApi = require('./app_api/routes/index');
var users = require('./app_server/routes/users');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'app_server', 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

I have also tried changing `app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));` to `app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));`

Any help would be appreciated. I tried to be as specific and detailed as possible.

-Edit- Here's what my model looks like:

```
var mongoose = require( 'mongoose' );

var openingTimeSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  days: {type: String, required: true},
  opening: String,
  closing: String,
  closed: {type: Boolean, required: true}
});

var reviewSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  author: String,
  rating: {type: Number, "default": 0, min: 0, max: 5},
  reviewText: String,
  createdOn: {type: Date, "default": Date.now}
});

var locationSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {type: String, required: true},
  address: String,
  rating: {type: Number, "default": 0, min: 0, max: 5},
  facilities: [String],
  coords: {type: [Number], index: '2dsphere', required: true},
  openingTimes: [openingTimeSchema],
  reviews: [reviewSchema]
});

mongoose.model('Location', locationSchema);
```

Comment: what data are you passing?

Comment: try with req.body.json()

Comment: I edited the my post to include my model. And I got TypeError: req.body.json is not a function

Comment: You haven't shared your request data.

Comment: I'm not sure how to get my req data, where do I find it? logging req to the console returns a huge amount of text, I'm not sure if that's what you want. Sorry for being clueless, I've been following a book on developing apps with the MEAN stack and get really stuck when things don't turn out like they should.

Comment: Your this code seems fine, I think you have selected the wrong type from where you are passing data

Comment: I’m not sure where I’m passing the data. Do you need to see my MongoDb document?

Answer (score 0):

I don't actually see you using the routes you imported used anywhere. But any plugin/middleware should be moved *above* wherever you use `app.use(myRoutes)`:

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

var index = require('./app_server/routes/index');
var indexApi = require('./app_api/routes/index');
var users = require('./app_server/routes/users');
```

Comment: I moved it above like you suggested and got app.use(bodyParser.json());
    ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'use' of undefined

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out my code was correct, I just did not correctly know how to use postman. I wasn't typing in any key-value pairs! I feel like an idiot guys. Thanks for the help[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qyf7C.png)